# How to loop through dbcontext all dbset in Entity Framework Core to get count?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have 20 Dbsets in my context which I want to get the row count for each dbset to make sure all dbset row count is 0. To get the count for one dbset, this is my code:

```
var person = context.Persons.Count();
```

Is there a way to loop through the context, get the count for each dbset dynamically?

Comment: Easy. But I think just get count is not enough. How do you plan to use this information?

Comment: Just to verify to make sure all table count is 0 before continue to some data import process. @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is solution. Usage is simple:

```cs
var tablesinfo = ctx.GetTablesInfo();
if (tablesinfo != null)
{
    var withRecords = tablesinfo
        .IgnoreQueryFilters()
        .Where(ti => ti.RecordCount > 0)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Extension returns `IQueryable<TableInfo>` and you can reuse this query later. Probably you will need to filter out Views, but I think you can handle that. Note that `IgnoreQueryFilters` can be important if you have Global Query Filters defined.

**What extension do:**

It scans Model for entity types registered for particular `DbContext` and generates big `Concat` of `Count` queries. Here we have to do that via grouping by constant value.

Schematically it will generate the following LINQ query:

```cs
var tablesinfo = 
            ctx.Set<Entity1>.GroupBy(e => 1).Select(g => new TableInfo { TableName = "Entity1", RecordCount = g.Count()})
    .Concat(ctx.Set<Entity2>.GroupBy(e => 1).Select(g => new TableInfo { TableName = "Entity2", RecordCount = g.Count()}))
    .Concat(ctx.Set<Entity3>.GroupBy(e => 1).Select(g => new TableInfo { TableName = "Entity3", RecordCount = g.Count()}))
    ...
```

Which wll be converted to the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT "Entity1" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM Entity1
UNION ALL
SELECT "Entity2" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM Entity2
UNION ALL
SELECT "Entity3" AS TableName, COUNT(*) AS RecordCount FROM Entity3
...
```

**Implementation:**

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public class TableInfo
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; } = null!;
        public int RecordCount { get; set; }
    }

    public static IQueryable<TableInfo> GetTablesInfo(this DbContext ctx)
    {
        Expression query = null;
        IQueryProvider provider = null;

        var ctxConst = Expression.Constant(ctx);
        var groupingKey = Expression.Constant(1);

        // gathering information for MemberInit creation 
        var newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(TableInfo).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
        var tableNameProperty = typeof(TableInfo).GetProperty(nameof(TableInfo.TableName));
        var recordCountProperty = typeof(TableInfo).GetProperty(nameof(TableInfo.RecordCount));

        foreach (var entityType in ctx.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            var entityParam = Expression.Parameter(entityType.ClrType, "e");
            var tableName = entityType.GetTableName();

            // ctx.Set<entityType>()
            var setQuery = Expression.Call(ctxConst, nameof(DbContext.Set), new[] {entityType.ClrType});

            // here we initialize IQueryProvider, which is needed for creating final query
            provider ??= ((IQueryable) Expression.Lambda(setQuery).Compile().DynamicInvoke()).Provider;

            // grouping paraneter has generic type, we have to specify it
            var groupingParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IGrouping<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(int), entityParam.Type), "g");

            // g => new TableInfo { TableName = "tableName", RecordCount = g.Count() }
            var selector = Expression.MemberInit(newExpression, 
                Expression.Bind(tableNameProperty, Expression.Constant(tableName)),
                Expression.Bind(recordCountProperty,
                    Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), nameof(Enumerable.Count), new[] {entityParam.Type}, groupingParameter)));

            // ctx.Set<entityType>.GroupBy(e => 1)
            var groupByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.GroupBy), new[]
                {
                    entityParam.Type,
                    typeof(int)
                },
                setQuery,
                Expression.Lambda(groupingKey, entityParam)
            );

            // ctx.Set<entityType>.GroupBy(e => 1).Select(g => new TableInfo { TableName = "tableName",  RecordCount = g.Count()}))
            groupByCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Select),
                new[] {groupingParameter.Type, typeof(TableInfo)}, 
                groupByCall,
                Expression.Lambda(selector, groupingParameter));

            // generate Concat if needed
            if (query != null)
                query = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), nameof(Queryable.Concat), new[] {typeof(TableInfo)}, query,
                    groupByCall);
            else
                query = groupByCall;
        }

        // unusual situation, but Model can have no registered entities
        if (query == null)
            return null;

        return provider.CreateQuery<TableInfo>(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using dependency injection and created my context at constructor for the context. So when I pass in _context, it says `cannot convert from 'xxx.Interfaces.IAbcContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'`

Comment: So you have created difficulties for yourself. Find a way to pass `DbContext` in proposed function. I know nothing about your interfaces and repositories.

Comment: For sure function can be rewritten to read properties. But this not original question.

Comment: downvoted because there are ZERO comments explaining what the GetTablesInfo method is doing.  How are people supposed to learn if you don't explain it?

Comment: @cdarrigo, enjoy. I hope it is clear now.