# Entity Framework Core counting tables and records Code-First Approach (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I've started using Entity Framework Core with Code-First approach and currently I'm not very used to it. My Entity Framework Core version is 3.1.20.

**Q: How to check how many tables available in some specific database?**

**Q: How to get the total record count in some specific database?**

**Q: How to get the total record count in some specific table?**

Comment: None of these queries seem to be really compatible with a typical use of entity framework; in the context of EF the answers would be "1) it doesn't matter, because you query what you have modeled and if a modeled table is unavailable you have a problem." "2) it doesn't make sense to ask, because EF is only concerned with those tables it knows about" and "3) it doesn't really make sense to ask, but you can ask eg `context.Users.Count()`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: How to check how many tables available in some specific database?

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64949899/10646316)

> Q: How to get the total record count in some specific database?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66115862/10646316) may help

```cs
var tablesinfo = ctx.GetTablesInfo();
var totalRecordCount = tablesinfo
    .IgnoreQueryFilters()
    .Sum(ti => ti.RecordCount);
```

> Q: How to get the total record count in some specific table?

```cs
var recordCount = ctx.SomeTable.Count();
```