# EF Core - Get count of multiple tables with one DB trip

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

For an admin page I need to provide several tables' total counts.

This is my current code:

```
[HttpGet("stats")]
public async Task<StatsVM> GetStats()
{
    var result = new StatsVM();

    result.TotalTable1 = await dbContext.Table1.CountAsync(...);
    result.TotalTable2 = await dbContext.Table2.CountAsync(...);
    result.TotalTable3 = await dbContext.Table3.CountAsync(...);
    result.TotalTable4 = await dbContext.Table4.CountAsync(...);

    return result;
}
```

To my understandings this will result in four DB trips (and there will be more in future). Is there a way to do it in one DB trip?

### Update:

Will the following code result in one DB trip? The query on `Table1` could be any non-empty table.

```
var result = await dbContext.Table1
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(c => new StatsVM
    {
        TotalTable1 = dbContext.Table1.Count(),
        TotalTable2 = dbContext.Table2.Count(),
        //...
    })
    .FirstAsync();
```

Comment: I don't think standard EF supports this. Every Count is a database call. I think this is one of the rare cases where a stored procedure or raw sql call would help. But this is just a hunch. Maybe EF has a trick up its sleeve.

Comment: Raw ADO.NET or Dapper for sugar coating  - not EF

Comment: Probably this [solution may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66112074/how-to-loop-through-dbcontext-all-dbset-in-entity-framework-core-to-get-count/66115862#66115862)

Comment: I have a piece of code that I want to know if it solves the problem. Should I update this question or ask a new one?

Comment: Well, I don't know if the code works. It's a question that if such code results in one DB trip.

Comment: You can add the code to your question, it won't invalidate the current answer.

Comment: You can monitor executed SQL right? Shouldn't be hard to find out how many roundtrips there are.

Comment: Could you please provide a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can map an entity type to a stored procedure that returns all the counts as a single row.